# Quotient group of dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups, quotient-group

Let $G=\{e,r^{2},...,r^{8},s,sr,...,sr^{8}\}$ and let $N=\langle r^{3} \rangle.$ Now let $\pi(g)=\bar{g}=gN$ be surjective with kernel $N$.

I have to show that $G/N=\{\bar{e},\bar{r},\bar{r^{2}},\bar{s},\bar{sr},\bar{sr^{2}} \}$ and I also need to compute a group table.

Now as far as I know, $G/N$ is the quotient group, which means that $G/N$ is a homomorphism with, for all $u,v \in G$, $uNvN=uvN$. But I have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestions
?

Comment: Note that in $G/N$, $\bar{r^3}=\bar e $, $\bar{r^4}= \bar r$, etc.

Comment: How come? I would say $\bar{r^{3}} = r^{3}N=r^{3}r^{3}=r^{6}$ if one would take $r^{3}$ from $N$ for example...

Comment: It is also true that $\bar {r^3}=\bar {r^6}$ in $G/N$

Comment: $r^3N=N$:   don't you see that $r^3\in N$  ?

Comment: $N$ is the identity element in the quotient group

Comment: You're right, I do see that $r^{3}N=N$ but not so much that for example $\overline{r^{4}}=\overline{r}$.

Comment: $r^3\in N$ so $r^4=rr^3\in rN$

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now :) Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\bar e =\bar {r^3}=\bar{r^6}, \bar r=\bar {r^4}=\bar{r^7}, \bar {r^2}=\bar{r^5}=\bar{r^8},$ and these equations can be left-multiplied by $\bar s.$

Thus $G/N=\{\bar{e},\bar{r},\bar{r^{2}},\bar{s},\bar{sr},\bar{sr^{2}} \}.$

$\bar e$ is the identity.

$\bar r \bar r=\bar {r^2}; \quad\bar {r^2} \bar {r^2} = \bar {r^4} = \bar r;\quad \bar r \bar {r^2}= \bar {r^2} \bar r = \bar e.$

You should be able to multiply $\bar r$ and $\bar {r^2}$ by $\bar s$, $\bar {sr}$, and $\bar {sr^2}$ and vice versa using these principles and knowledge of multiplication in $G.$

Answer (score 1):

This is known as "killing $r^3$," since by quotienting out by $N$ you are changing the presentation

$$\langle r, s\mid r^9, s^2, srs^{-1}=r^{-1}\rangle$$

to

$$\langle r, s\mid r^9=r^3=1, s^2, srs^{-1}=r^{-1}\rangle,$$

but then $r^9=(r^3)^3=1$, which gives the presentation

$$\langle r, s\mid r^3, s^2, srs^{-1}=r^{-1}\rangle,$$

whose elements of the group it defines are exactly the ones you need. Can you check that yourself?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Nicely put, I wasnt familiar with "killing" but the terminology makes sense.

Comment: @Shaun:  are you saying that  $r^8=e$ in $G$?  In OP's question, it appears to me that $r^8$ is distinct from $e$, so I thought $r^9=e$

Comment: You're right, @J.W.Tanner; thank you! I've corrected it now.